# Active Navigation Menu Highlight for Current Page from a Single Header File

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

How can I make the navigation menu get highlighted for the current page that I am visiting?

header.php

```
<div class="header-menu">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <a href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Register</li></a>
      <a href="login.php"><li>Login</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>FAQ</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Advertise</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Terms</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Support</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Forum</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I am currently on the `login.php` page, then in the navigation menu the login item should be highlighted (like bg color change). I can do this in PHP using conditional logic to set an active class by setting a variable on each page which identifies the current page.

For example something like `if($page == 2){ echo "active" }`

But, I want to achieve this using CSS. I have googled this and found ways of adding active class on "each" page which is very simple but the problem is I have my navigation menu on a single header file where that method requires to have menu on all the pages separately.

How can I achieve this using CSS, or Javascript / jQuery if it is not possible using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure JavaScript and HTML.

```html
<a href="index.php" class="myLink" data-pathname="/index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
<a href="forum.php" class="myLink" data-pathname="/forum.php"><li>Forum</li></a>
```

If needed active class in `<li>` instead of anchor tag `<a>`

```html
<a href="index.php"><li class="myLink" data-pathname="/index.php">Home</li></a>
<a href="forum.php"><li class="myLink" data-pathname="/forum.php">Forum</li></a>
```

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("myLink");
var URL = window.location.pathname;
URL = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/'));
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].dataset.pathname == URL) {
    links[i].classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223000/discussion-on-answer-by-anvay-active-navigation-menu-highlight-for-current-page).